# Can't start adb

Tags: android, adb

Running vista when I execute adb nodaemon server with ADB_TRACE=ALL it shows that adb can't bind to port 5037. Any suggestions what the problem is or where to investigate would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this may seem obvious, but you'll get that error if you try to start adb when it is already running.  I don't know the specific process for the task manager in Vista, but be sure it isn't already running.

I was able to reproduce and resolve your issue by killing the automatically started adb and then running: `adb nodaemon server ADB_TRACE=ALL` from the command line.